# How do you get the IP addresses of KVM guests that are using a Bridge Network Device from the KVM host

Tags: networking, ip, kvm-virtualization

Does anyone know of a way using KVM to find out the IP addresses of KVM guests that are using a bridge interface (br0) through the KVM host? Currently I have br0 setup with a single NIC (eth0) included. The KVM host is a system running CentOS 5.6 in case that matters. The guests are also running CentOS 5.6.

BTW, the guests do not just show up in the KVM host's arp table, I'm looking for better solutions and/or leads.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only proper way of achieving this is to have a service in the guest that would report guest data (IP, software installed, etc) to the host using the hyperchannel.
This is already available in RHEV for windows guests, and will be available for linux guests soon enough as well.
If you want to get your own stuff done, you can write such an agent yourself - this is open source after all